# Regex in XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to extract some data from XML field using XSLT 2.0 and I don't know the best way to do that.
Here is my XML value:

```
<PayReaCom>AP@1267347323/11122/01/2017/REF1AP@</PayReaCom>
```

And I need everything between `AP@` and `AP@`; so in this case:

```
1267347323/11122/01/2017/REF1
```

I tried using `substring`, but I don't know how to set restrictions for `AP@`.

Can I use a regular expression here?

Comment: Will there always be two `AP@` strings, one at the beginning and one at he end? If so, you could simply cut off the first and the last 3 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `PayReaCom` element is the context node, to print the required
fragment, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'AP@'), 'AP@')"/>
```

First `substring-after` function "cuts off" the initial `AP@` (and whatever was
before).
Then the result of this function is processed by `substring-before` function,
which "cuts off" the second instance of `AP@` (and whatever was after).

Or if you want to save this substring in a variable, use:

```
<xsl:variable name="yourName" .../>
```

with the `select` clause as above.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, you could do simply:

```
tokenize($string, 'AP@')[2]
```

to return the string in-between the first and the second occurrences of the `AP@` delimiter.

---

For example, given:

```
<PayReaCom>alphaAP@bravoAP@charlie</PayReaCom>
```

the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(PayReaCom, 'AP@')[2]" />
```

will return:

```
bravo
```

Comment: Do you think it would be the fastest way?

Comment: I would not expect to see a *significant* performance difference - but you need to test such things yourself, using your actual production environment.

Answer (score 0):

## `xsl:analyze-string`

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="PayReaCom" regex="AP@(.+?)AP@">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <!-- Replacement here -->
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string

You may want to use this in conjunction with the function: `regex-group`.

See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-regex-group